# Puppet : How to load file from agent - Part 3

Tags: puppet

Using the functions in my earlier queries (see reference below), I am able to pull the file from the agent and perform the necessary tasks. However, this is affecting all the users on the system as it throws an exception stating that the file is not found. Is there anyway I can add some logic like `unless file_exists ....` to this ruby function ?

My hierarchy is shown below. I am not following why it affects other users who are not even in "mymodules".

```
Root
  modules
     mymodules
        lib
          facter
             ruby_function1.rb
             ruby_function2.rb
     modules_by_userxx1
     modules_by_userxx2
     modules_by_userxx3
     ....
```

Reference :
[Puppet : How to load file from agent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43808941/352403)

[Puppet : How to load file from agent - Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43808941/352403)

As requested by Dominic, adding reference code :

```
# module_name/lib/facter/master_hash.rb
require 'json'
Facter.add(:master_hash) do
  setcode do
    # return content of foo as a string
    f = File.read('/path/to/some_file.json')
    master_hash = JSON.parse(f)
    master_hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about the custom fact from the previous answers rather than a Ruby function, in which case, add a `File.exist?` conditional:

```
# module_name/lib/facter/master_hash.rb
require 'json'
Facter.add(:master_hash) do
  setcode do
    if File.exist?('/path/to/some_file.json')
      # return content of foo as a string
      f = File.read('/path/to/some_file.json')
      master_hash = JSON.parse(f)
      master_hash
    end
  end
end
```

Please include the full error message (with the filename/line number it provides) and the source code when asking questions.

Custom facts are shipped within modules, but are *all* synced to agents as they're used to discover data.

Facts are synced and run on agents before the node is classified because they can be used to make classification and catalog decisions, e.g. based on hostname or OS. Because facts run before classification, it isn't yet possible to know which classes (and perhaps modules) are going to be applied, so should be safe to run on every node in the environment.